# Eclipse remote debugging hot deploy

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jvm, remote-debugging

I am doing some remote debugging with Eclipse attaching the a running JBoss server with EAR deployed.

Most of the time, when I am connected to the remote JVM, I can hot-deploy my change, i.e.
I can change the code in Eclipse and then it deploys.

On some occasions, the JVM just crashes with the error below (if I save my code changes and Eclipse tries to deploy)
(which means I have to re-compile the class, copy it to the lib folder of the ear etc)

What is causing this and how to fix it?

Environment:

- Jboss trinity 4.2.2
- Spring source tool suite 2.3.2
- JVM Hotspot 64-bit

```
     # An unexpected error has been detected by HotSpot Virtual Machine:
     #
     #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000008275f84, pid=5764, tid=3552
     #
     # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (1.5.0_22-b03 mixed mode)
     # Problematic frame:
     # V  [jvm.dll+0x275f84]
     #
     # An error report file with more information is saved as hs_err_pid5764.log
     #
     # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
     #   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
     #
     Press any key to continue . . .
```

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000005e9cf40):  VMThread [id=3552]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
EAX=0x000000000020dc00, EBX=0x000000004300b680, ECX=0x0000000000000000, EDX=0x0000000000222880
ESP=0x000000000622fc80, EBP=0x000000000653f8e0, ESI=0x000000000020dbf0, EDI=0x00000000002b9700
EIP=0x0000000008275f84, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000000622fc80)
0x000000000622fc80:   0000000005f54440 000000004300b680
0x000000000622fc90:   000000000020dbf0 00000000002b9700
0x000000000622fca0:   0000000000000000 0000000005e9cf40
0x000000000622fcb0:   000000000020dbf0 000000000020dc00
0x000000000622fcc0:   00000000002b9700 000000000020dfd8
0x000000000622fcd0:   0000000000000002 000007feff661332
0x000000000622fce0:   0000000009102a50 0000000000000001
0x000000000622fcf0:   0000000005e9cf40 00000000002b9730
0x000000000622fd00:   0000000000222860 0000000000222878
0x000000000622fd10:   0000000000222c48 000000000622fe18
0x000000000622fd20:   000000000020dc00 0000000000000018
0x000000000622fd30:   0000000005f54440 0000000000000000
0x000000000622fd40:   0000000005e9cf40 000000000020dfd8
0x000000000622fd50:   000000000020dfd8 000000000653f8e0
0x000000000622fd60:   00000000093606e0 00000000082772eb
0x000000000622fd70:   000000000653f8e0 00000000082d1440 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000008275f84)
0x0000000008275f74:   7a 01 00 00 66 66 66 90 66 66 66 90 48 8b 48 08
0x0000000008275f84:   8b 01 ff c8 4c 63 c0 0f 88 3a 01 00 00 48 8b 41 


Stack: [0x0000000006130000,0x0000000006230000),  sp=0x000000000622fc80,  free space=1023k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x275f84]

VM_Operation (0x000000000653f870): change breakpoints, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x0000000005eb75b0


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000005345a1d0 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4228]
  0x0000000053459f20 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2476]
  0x0000000053459710 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5088]
  0x0000000053459460 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5180]
  0x00000000534591b0 JavaThread "File Reaper" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6356]
  0x0000000053458f00 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6220]
  0x000000000b10f1a0 JavaThread "JDWP Command Reader" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2700]
  0x0000000053458c50 JavaThread "ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6124]
  0x00000000534589a0 JavaThread "ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-CometPoller-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2860]
  0x00000000534586f0 JavaThread "ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-CometPoller-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6864]
  0x0000000007804a00 JavaThread "ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-CometPoller-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6924]
  0x0000000007804750 JavaThread "ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-CometPoller-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3560]
  0x00000000078044a0 JavaThread "ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-CometPoller-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4504]
  0x00000000078041f0 JavaThread "ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-CometPoller-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6948]
  0x0000000007803f40 JavaThread "ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-CometPoller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3716]
  0x0000000007803c90 JavaThread "ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-CometPoller-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1136]
  0x00000000078039e0 JavaThread "ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-Poller-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3656]
  0x0000000007803730 JavaThread "ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-Poller-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5868]
  0x0000000007803480 JavaThread "ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-Poller-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2512]
  0x00000000078031d0 JavaThread "ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-Poller-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6248]
  0x0000000007802f20 JavaThread "ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-Poller-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4592]
  0x00000000540994a0 JavaThread "ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-Poller-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5984]
  0x00000000540991f0 JavaThread "ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-Poller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5232]
  0x0000000054098f40 JavaThread "ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-Poller-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5928]
  0x0000000054098c90 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7104]
  0x00000000540989e0 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-CometPoller-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4008]
  0x0000000054098730 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-CometPoller-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4784]
  0x0000000054098480 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-CometPoller-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6760]
  0x00000000540981d0 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-CometPoller-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6164]
  0x0000000054097f20 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-CometPoller-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5484]
  0x0000000054097c70 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-CometPoller-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5476]
  0x00000000540979c0 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-CometPoller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2132]
  0x0000000055369550 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-CometPoller-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5804]
  0x00000000553692a0 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Poller-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4312]
  0x0000000055368ff0 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Poller-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5772]
  0x0000000055368d40 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Poller-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5624]
  0x0000000055368a90 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Poller-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6776]
  0x0000000009814950 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Poller-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6616]
  0x00000000098146a0 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Poller-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5332]
  0x00000000098143f0 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Poller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6256]
  0x0000000009814140 JavaThread "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Poller-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4072]
  0x0000000009813e90 JavaThread "Thread-6" [_thread_blocked, id=3468]
  0x0000000009813be0 JavaThread "JBossLifeThread" [_thread_blocked, id=4904]
  0x0000000009813930 JavaThread "FLEXlm Heartbeat" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5040]
  0x0000000009813680 JavaThread "Thread-44" [_thread_in_native, id=6780]
  0x00000000098133d0 JavaThread "NCI-NativeErrorLogger" [_thread_blocked, id=5036]
  0x0000000009813120 JavaThread "NCI-ProcessMonitor" [_thread_blocked, id=2872]
  0x0000000009812e70 JavaThread "NCI-ProcessStarter" [_thread_blocked, id=6312]
  0x0000000006e7e3d0 JavaThread "NCI-RemoteLogger" [_thread_in_native, id=4620]
  0x0000000006e7e120 JavaThread "Timer-3" [_thread_blocked, id=4400]
  0x0000000006e7de70 JavaThread "FLEXlm Heartbeat" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4104]
  0x0000000006e7d910 JavaThread "QuartzScheduler_quartzSchedulerFactory-NON_CLUSTERED_MisfireHandler" [_thread_blocked, id=5908]
  0x0000000008578b60 JavaThread "quartzSchedulerFactory_QuartzSchedulerThread" [_thread_blocked, id=1712]
  0x00000000085788b0 JavaThread "quartzSchedulerFactory_Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=1216]
  0x0000000008578600 JavaThread "quartzSchedulerFactory_Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=4524]
  0x0000000008578350 JavaThread "quartzSchedulerFactory_Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=4316]
  0x000000000c28cd30 JavaThread "taskExecutor-5" [_thread_blocked, id=7052]
  0x000000000c28ca80 JavaThread "taskExecutor-4" [_thread_blocked, id=516]
  0x000000000c28c7d0 JavaThread "taskExecutor-3" [_thread_blocked, id=4748]
  0x000000000c28bd10 JavaThread "taskExecutor-2" [_thread_blocked, id=3652]
  0x000000000c28c520 JavaThread "taskExecutor-1" [_thread_blocked, id=5128]
  0x000000000c28afa0 JavaThread "Thread-35" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3372]
  0x000000000c28acf0 JavaThread "Thread-34" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3880]
  0x000000000c28aa40 JavaThread "Thread-33" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6384]
  0x000000000c28a790 JavaThread "Thread-32" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1384]
  0x000000000c28a4e0 JavaThread "Thread-31" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2336]
  0x000000000c28a230 JavaThread "Thread-30" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3824]
  0x000000000c289f80 JavaThread "Thread-29" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5596]
  0x000000000c289cd0 JavaThread "Thread-28" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3928]
  0x000000000c289a20 JavaThread "Thread-27" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5788]
  0x000000000c289770 JavaThread "Thread-26" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4056]
  0x000000000c2894c0 JavaThread "Thread-25" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7140]
  0x000000000c289210 JavaThread "Thread-24" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5840]
  0x00000000091dc880 JavaThread "Thread-23" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5852]
  0x00000000091dc5d0 JavaThread "Thread-22" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6052]
  0x00000000091dc320 JavaThread "Thread-21" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7092]
  0x00000000091dc070 JavaThread "Thread-20" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5208]
  0x00000000091dbdc0 JavaThread "Thread-19" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4576]
  0x00000000091dbb10 JavaThread "Thread-18" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6888]
  0x00000000091db860 JavaThread "Thread-17" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5560]
  0x00000000091db5b0 JavaThread "Thread-16" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4780]
  0x00000000091db300 JavaThread "Thread-15" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=760]
  0x00000000091db050 JavaThread "Thread-14" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6716]
  0x00000000091dada0 JavaThread "Thread-13" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5132]
  0x00000000091daaf0 JavaThread "Thread-12" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1372]
  0x00000000091da840 JavaThread "Thread-11" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6432]
  0x00000000091da590 JavaThread "Thread-10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3280]
  0x00000000091d9d80 JavaThread "JCA PoolFiller" [_thread_blocked, id=6288]
  0x00000000091da2e0 JavaThread "HSQLDB Timer @71eca460" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3600]
  0x00000000091da030 JavaThread "UILServerILService Accept Thread" [_thread_in_native, id=3380]
  0x00000000091d9570 JavaThread "Timer-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6036]
  0x00000000091d9ad0 JavaThread "TimeoutFactory-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3916]
  0x00000000091d9820 JavaThread "IdleRemover" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2532]
  0x00000000091d92c0 JavaThread "WorkManager(2)-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6724]
  0x00000000091d9010 JavaThread "Thread-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5956]
  0x00000000091d8d60 JavaThread "JBossMQ Cache Reference Softner" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2900]
  0x00000000090aae50 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5220]
  0x00000000090aaba0 JavaThread "SubscriptionWatchDog" [_thread_blocked, id=1280]
  0x00000000090aa390 JavaThread "ServerSocketRefresh" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6688]
  0x00000000090aa0e0 JavaThread "AcceptorThread#0:3873" [_thread_in_native, id=3204]
  0x00000000090a9e30 JavaThread "ServerSocketRefresh" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5824]
  0x00000000090a9b80 JavaThread "AcceptorThread#0:4446" [_thread_in_native, id=2244]
  0x00000000090a98d0 JavaThread "PooledInvokerAcceptor#0-4445" [_thread_in_native, id=4564]
  0x00000000090a9620 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-4444" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5312]
  0x000000000a2fb2c0 JavaThread "Listener:60034" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6308]
  0x000000000a2fb010 JavaThread "Thread-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6656]
  0x000000000a2fad60 JavaThread "Thread-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7024]
  0x000000000a2faab0 JavaThread "Listener:60031" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6880]
  0x000000000a2fa800 JavaThread "JBoss System Threads(1)-2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5080]
  0x000000000a2fa550 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5660]
  0x000000000a2fa2a0 JavaThread "RMI Reaper" [_thread_blocked, id=6784]
  0x000000000a2f9ff0 JavaThread "Timer-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6676]
  0x000000000a2f9d40 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-1098" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3980]
  0x000000000a2f9a90 JavaThread "JBoss System Threads(1)-1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6932]
  0x000000000a2f97e0 JavaThread "ScannerThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5812]
  0x000000000798d8b0 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3376]
  0x00000000001f97d0 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=3292]
  0x0000000005ec4a40 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7072]
  0x0000000005ec3ee0 JavaThread "CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6620]
  0x0000000005ec3b50 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5160]
  0x0000000005ec27c0 JavaThread "AdapterThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2260]
  0x0000000005ec0190 JavaThread "JDWP Event Helper Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5060]
  0x0000000005eb75b0 JavaThread "JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6732]
  0x0000000005ea1e10 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5988]
  0x0000000005ea0b50 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4916]

Other Threads:
=>0x0000000005e9cf40 VMThread [id=3552]
  0x000000000022bf40 WatcherThread [id=4408]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x000000000033fcd0/0x0000000000000100] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x0000000005e9cf40

Heap
 par new generation   total 205952K, used 70156K [0x0000000010010000, 0x000000001f160000, 0x000000001f160000)
  eden space 164800K,  27% used [0x0000000010010000, 0x0000000012c155b8, 0x000000001a100000)
  from space 41152K,  60% used [0x000000001a100000, 0x000000001b97dd58, 0x000000001c930000)
  to   space 41152K,   0% used [0x000000001c930000, 0x000000001c930000, 0x000000001f160000)
 tenured generation   total 494272K, used 73607K [0x000000001f160000, 0x000000003d410000, 0x000000003d410000)
   the space 494272K,  14% used [0x000000001f160000, 0x0000000023941ef8, 0x0000000023942000, 0x000000003d410000)
 compacting perm gen  total 131072K, used 107397K [0x000000003d410000, 0x0000000045410000, 0x000000004d410000)
   the space 131072K,  81% used [0x000000003d410000, 0x0000000043cf1778, 0x0000000043cf1800, 0x0000000045410000)
No shared spaces configured.

Dynamic libraries:
0x0000000000400000 - 0x0000000000412000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\jdk64\bin\java.exe
0x0000000077690000 - 0x000000007783b000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000077570000 - 0x000000007768f000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefd6a0000 - 0x000007fefd70b000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007fefd9c0000 - 0x000007fefda9b000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007feff660000 - 0x000007feff6ff000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007feff7a0000 - 0x000007feff7bf000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefee70000 - 0x000007fefef9e000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000008000000 - 0x0000000008562000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\jdk64\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x0000000077470000 - 0x000000007756a000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007feff130000 - 0x000007feff197000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefefe0000 - 0x000007fefefee000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefeff0000 - 0x000007feff0ba000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefb930000 - 0x000007fefb96b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x000007fefefa0000 - 0x000007fefefce000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007feff380000 - 0x000007feff489000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x0000000010000000 - 0x000000001000b000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\jdk64\jre\bin\hpi.dll
0x0000000077860000 - 0x0000000077867000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x0000000000360000 - 0x00000000003b0000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\jdk64\jre\bin\jdwp.dll
0x00000000003e0000 - 0x00000000003f1000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\jdk64\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x00000000005b0000 - 0x00000000005dd000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\jdk64\jre\bin\java.dll
0x00000000026d0000 - 0x00000000026e6000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\jdk64\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00000000003c0000 - 0x00000000003ca000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\jdk64\jre\bin\dt_socket.dll
0x000007feff0c0000 - 0x000007feff10d000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefefd0000 - 0x000007fefefd8000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefce20000 - 0x000007fefce74000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefc6e0000 - 0x000007fefc6e7000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x0000000006540000 - 0x000000000655b000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\jdk64\jre\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefce10000 - 0x000007fefce17000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x000007fefb740000 - 0x000007fefb755000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x000007fefcca0000 - 0x000007fefccfb000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x000007fefa180000 - 0x000007fefa18b000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x000007fefa0d0000 - 0x000007fefa0e5000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x000007fefa0f0000 - 0x000007fefa109000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x000007fefa460000 - 0x000007fefa470000     C:\Windows\system32\wshbth.dll
0x000007fefaac0000 - 0x000007fefaae7000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fefaa20000 - 0x000007fefaa2b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fefa1c0000 - 0x000007fefa1c8000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x000007fefa880000 - 0x000007fefa8d3000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x0000000006560000 - 0x000000000656a000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\jdk64\jre\bin\management.dll
0x000007fefce80000 - 0x000007fefce97000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefcb80000 - 0x000007fefcbc7000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefcab0000 - 0x000007fefcace000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x000007fefd5f0000 - 0x000007fefd5ff000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x000007fefd4e0000 - 0x000007fefd4ef000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000000000d6d0000 - 0x000000000d7ed000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\jboss\bin\native\tcnative-1.dll
0x000007feff280000 - 0x000007feff2f1000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x0000000000300000 - 0x000000000030c000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\jdk64\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x000000000e130000 - 0x000000000e34b000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\jdk64\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x000007fefac50000 - 0x000007fefacc0000     C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x000007fefec10000 - 0x000007fefee11000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x0000000000310000 - 0x0000000000330000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\jboss\server\default\deploy\erdas-apollo.ear\apollo-iws.war\WEB-INF\classes\NativeUtil.dll
0x0000000180000000 - 0x0000000180013000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\jboss\server\default\deploy\erdas-apollo.ear\conf\IWSServerNative.dll
0x000000004d610000 - 0x000000004d97d000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\native\iws\bin\NCSSUtilApollo.dll
0x000007fefd710000 - 0x000007fefd7b0000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7600.16385_none_a44af8ec57f961cf\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007feff5c0000 - 0x000007feff658000     C:\Windows\system32\comdlg32.dll
0x000007fefde80000 - 0x000007fefec06000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007feff1a0000 - 0x000007feff277000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x000000004d980000 - 0x000000004dc81000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\native\iws\bin\NCSEcw4.dll
0x0000000007190000 - 0x00000000071bc000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\native\iws\bin\tbb.dll
0x0000000074970000 - 0x0000000074a79000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4927_none_88dce9872fb18caf\MSVCP80.dll
0x0000000074af0000 - 0x0000000074bb9000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4927_none_88dce9872fb18caf\MSVCR80.dll
0x00000000071d0000 - 0x00000000071ed000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\native\iws\bin\NCScnet4.dll
0x000007fefd7b0000 - 0x000007fefd916000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x000007fefd690000 - 0x000007fefd69f000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x000007fefcaa0000 - 0x000007fefcaa9000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x0000000007610000 - 0x0000000007694000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\native\iws\bin\NCSUtil4.dll
0x000007fefc610000 - 0x000007fefc61c000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x000007feff110000 - 0x000007feff127000     C:\Windows\system32\imagehlp.dll
0x000000000e450000 - 0x000000000e514000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\native\iws\bin\ermapper_ng_u.dll
0x000000004dc90000 - 0x000000004e465000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\native\iws\bin\ermapper_u.dll
0x0000000007f60000 - 0x0000000007ff7000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\native\iws\bin\bmg.dll
0x000000000b9f0000 - 0x000000000baa0000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\native\iws\bin\GeoCalcPBW.dll
0x000000004e470000 - 0x000000004e9ee000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\native\iws\bin\GeoCalc.dll
0x000000004e9f0000 - 0x000000004ec8b000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\native\iws\bin\xerces-c_2_7.dll
0x000000000f850000 - 0x000000000f9a3000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\native\iws\bin\xsec_1_3_0.dll
0x000000004ec90000 - 0x000000004ed3a000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\native\iws\bin\GMLCRS.dll
0x000000004ed40000 - 0x000000004ee12000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\native\iws\bin\NCSOTDF.dll
0x000000000d270000 - 0x000000000d296000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\native\iws\bin\libjpeg.dll
0x000007fefca80000 - 0x000007fefca96000     C:\Windows\system32\NETAPI32.dll
0x000007fefca70000 - 0x000007fefca7c000     C:\Windows\system32\netutils.dll
0x000007fefd120000 - 0x000007fefd143000     C:\Windows\system32\srvcli.dll
0x000007fefca50000 - 0x000007fefca65000     C:\Windows\system32\wkscli.dll
0x000000004ee20000 - 0x000000004f038000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\native\iws\bin\ecwpApollo.dll
0x000000000f280000 - 0x000000000f2dd000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\native\iws\bin\JPIPServerApollo.dll
0x000000004f040000 - 0x000000004f0e7000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\native\iws\bin\kdu_v52.dll
0x000007fefa780000 - 0x000007fefa791000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x000007fefa5d0000 - 0x000007fefa5e8000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x0000000071240000 - 0x0000000071243000     C:\Windows\system32\icmp.Dll
0x000007fefd450000 - 0x000007fefd475000     C:\Windows\system32\SspiCli.dll
0x0000000054650000 - 0x0000000054838000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\jboss\server\default\deploy\erdas-apollo.ear\conf\JeckerHelper.dll
0x000007fefbf50000 - 0x000007fefc144000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7600.16385_none_fa645303170382f6\COMCTL32.dll
0x00000000570d0000 - 0x00000000572b7000     C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\jboss\server\default\deploy\erdas-apollo.ear\conf\lmgr11.dll
0x000007fefd980000 - 0x000007fefd9ba000     C:\Windows\system32\WINTRUST.dll
0x000007fefb260000 - 0x000007fefb271000     C:\Windows\system32\wtsapi32.dll
0x000007fefd480000 - 0x000007fefd4d7000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
```

VM Arguments:

```
jvm_args: -Djava.library.path=C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\jboss\bin\native;C:/work/ERDAS/APOLLO2010.1/tools/native/fme -Dprogram.name=run.bat -Xrs -Xms724m -Xmx724m -Xss64k -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -XX:SurvivorRatio=4 -XX:+UseParNewGC -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\jboss\lib\endorsed
java_command: org.jboss.Main -b 0.0.0.0
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD
```

Environment Variables:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:/work/ERDAS/APOLLO2010.1/tools/jdk64
PATH=C:/work/ERDAS/APOLLO2010.1/tools/native/iws/bin;C:/work/ERDAS/APOLLO2010.1/tools/native/fme;C:/work/ERDAS/APOLLO2010.1/tools/native/fme;C:/work/ERDAS/APOLLO2010.1/tools/native/fme;C:/work/ERDAS/APOLLO2010.1/tools/native/fme;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\NTRU Cryptosystems\NTRU TCG Software Stack\bin\;C:\Program Files\NTRU Cryptosystems\NTRU TCG Software Stack\bin\;C:\Program Files\Wave Systems Corp\Gemalto\Access Client\v5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\10.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\work\bin\maven\bin;C:\work\bin\apache-ant-1.8.1\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\work\bin;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\work\ERDAS\APOLLO2010.1\tools\native\iws\ermlib\third_party\win64
USERNAME=lchandra
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel

---------------  S Y S T E M  --------------    
OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7600     
CPU:total 4 em64t ht    
Memory: 4k page, physical 4118360k(1027192k free), swap 5140460k(1238364k free)    
vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (1.5.0_22-b03) for windows-amd64, built on Oct  9 2009 00:35:21 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1400    
time: Mon Jul 19 11:42:00 2010
elapsed time: 201 seconds
```